# Avoid pause with screenreader

Tags: jaws-screen-reader

I want to display prices like this : 
299<sub>,90€</sub>

```
<span>299<sub>,90€</sub></span>
```

How to avoid NVDA to make pause between 299 and 90.
It says : "299" and then "90 euros".

I tried using aria-label but without a role, label is not read:

```
<span aria-label="299,90€">299<sub>,90€</sub></span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even with 299,90€ with no subscript, screen readers (I'm using JAWS at the moment), still reads a pause between the two parts.  It may be a language/i18n difference in the voice synthesizer.  If I format it as 299.90€, JAWS reads "299 point 90 euros".

The blog post at https://www.deque.com/blog/dont-screen-readers-read-whats-screen-part-1-punctuation-typographic-symbols/#currency has some rough information.

I know if I put a lang="fr" on the span for example, JAWS reads in French, but that's not really the desired effect for a currency value.

You can also try an approach like [Screen reader is not reading the price ("$47.49") properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812616/screen-reader-is-not-reading-the-price-47-49-properly)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll look at this.