# Use aria-label on a span

Tags: html, ios, wai-aria, voiceover

I'm showing product ratings using Unicode star symbols. iOS VoiceOver doesn't read this aloud correctly, so I thought I'd use `aria-label` on my span to tell screen readers what it means.

```html
<span aria-label="4.0 stars out of 5, 123 ratings">★★★★☆ 4.0 (123)</span>
```

It's not working. iOS VoiceOver ignores my `aria-label` completely.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `aria-label` is sometimes ignored by some assistive technology if the element you put it on doesn't have any semantic meaning.  A <span> doesn't have semantic meaning.  If you add a [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) that is appropriate for your stars, then it should be read correctly.

Comment: Furthermore, the ARIA standard explicitly states that naming `generic` roles is prohibited.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [*mdn web doc*'s `aria-label` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label):

> Not all elements can be given an accessible name. Neither aria-label nor aria-labelledby should be used with non-interactive elements or inline structural role such as with code, term, or emphasis nor roles whose semantics will not be mapped to the accessibility API, including presentation, none, and hidden. The aria-label attribute is intended for interactive elements only.

So that's why `aria-label` has no effect on `<span>` elements: `<span>` is a non-interactive element without semantics.

But here is what you can do: provide two `<span>`s, each expressing the same information but for separate "target groups":

- One `<span>` is the visual no-screenreader version; the attribute `aria-hidden="true"` will make sure it will not be part of the *accessibility tree* and therefore not be communicated by screen readers to their users.
- One `<span>` is the accessible screenreader version: CSS styling takes care of *visually* hiding it.

Reusing [Bootstrap 5's `.visually-hidden` CSS class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/helpers/visually-hidden/), your example can be rewritten like so:

```css
.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: -1px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0) !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<span aria-hidden="true">★★★★☆ 4.0 (123)</span>
<span class="visually-hidden">4.0 stars out of 5, 123 ratings</span>
```

- Visually, this will **only** present "4 black Unicode stars, 1 white Unicode star, *4.0*, and *123* in parentheses".
- For screen readers, this will **only** present "*4.0 stars out of 5, 123 ratings*".

Comment: I think the issue here is that search engines would probably index both the spans and not check to see if one is hidden. I know sometimes they check for hidden things, but I don't think its the norm.

Answer (score 4):

One method would be to add a `role=img`

```
<span aria-label="4.0 stars out of 5, 123 ratings" role="img">★★★★☆ 4.0 (123)</span>
```

Comment: role="img" might seem inappropriate but other roles like "note" don't work, so I'll use that.

Comment: Voiceover will read it as ".... image" so, it isn't accurate.