# How to make li tababble and readable by screenreader?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have the following list and I want each list item to be readable by screenreader.
However, the list and listitems themselves are not tababble.
Adding tabindex="0" is not really option because voiceover announces the listitem as a group and being interactive, when it is isn't.
Any idea?

```
<ul>
    <li key={i}>
        <span>{date}</span>
        <span>{value}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The 2nd answer on the following link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54141817/use-aria-label-on-a-span

Answer (score 2):

first of all, ask yourself why you want the `li`s to be tabbable (i.e., focusable by keyboard).
If the contents inside these `li`s must be clickable (i.e., really interactive), then mark it as such (as links, for instance). If not (i.e., the contents is, well, just text), then just don't make it focusable, you'll confuse your users. Please comment on my answer and/or update the question, probably I'll be more thorough then.