# Screenreaders reading monetary amount

Tags: html, accessibility

I would like a screen reader like narrator to read strings like

```
216,50 SEK
```

on my webpage as

> 216 kronor and 50 öre

(our currency is krona and the sub currency is öre)

Is that possible using some aria trickery?

Comment: Users [may be confused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37849100/14956277) by hearing a currency value in a format other than what's normal for their screen reader.

Comment: I am really positive that you present the similar question as you do, but not close voting. That is what a welcoming stackoverflow should be made of. I will remove this question because the other one describes the correct approach which is "do not do anything".